# Sequential Binary Data Decoding Using Conduits

Tags: haskell, protocol-buffers, conduit

The goal is to have a conduit with the following type signature

```
protobufConduit :: MonadResource m => (ByteString -> a) -> Conduit ByteString m a
```

The conduit should repeatedly parse protocol buffers (using the `ByteString -> a` function) received via TCP/IP (using the `network-conduit` package).

The wire message format is

```
{length (32 bits big endian)}{protobuf 1}{length}{protobuf 2}...
```

(The curly braces are not party of the protocol, only used here to separate the entities).

The first idea was to use `sequenceSink` to repeatedly apply a `Sink` that is able to parse one ProtoBuf:

```
[...]
import qualified Data.Binary         as B
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import qualified Data.Conduit.Util   as CU

protobufConduit :: MonadResource m => (ByteString -> a) -> Conduit ByteString m a
protobufConduit protobufDecode =
    CU.sequenceSink () $ \() ->
        do lenBytes <- CB.take 4                                -- read protobuf length
           let len :: Word32
               len = B.decode lengthBytes                       -- decode ProtoBuf length
               intLen = fromIntegral len
           protobufBytes <- CB.take intLen                      -- read the ProtoBuf bytes
           return $ CU.Emit () [ protobufDecode protobufBytes ] -- emit decoded ProtoBuf
```

It doens't work (only works for the first protocol buffer) because there seems to be a number of "leftover" bytes already read from the source but not consumed via `CB.take` that get discarded.

And I found no way of pushing "the rest back into the source".

Did I get the concept entirely wrong?

PS: Even if I use protocol buffers here, the problem is not related to protocol buffers. To debug the problem I always use `{length}{UTF8 encoded string}{length}{UTF8 encoded string}...` and a conduit similar to the above one (`utf8StringConduit :: MonadResource m =>  Conduit ByteString m Text`).

#### Update:

I just tried to replace the state (no state `()` in the sample above) by the remaining bytes and replaced the `CB.take` calls by calls to a function that first consumes the already read bytes (from the state) and calls `await` only as needed (when the state is not large enough). Unfortunately, that doesn't work either because as soon as the Source has no bytes left, `sequenceSink` does not execute the code but the state still contains the remaining bytes :-(.

If you should be interested in the code (which isn't optimized or very good but should be enough to test):

```
utf8StringConduit :: forall m. MonadResource m => Conduit ByteString m Text
utf8StringConduit =
    CU.sequenceSink [] $ \st ->
        do (lengthBytes, st') <- takeWithState BS.empty st 4
           let len :: Word32
               len = B.decode $ BSL.fromChunks [lengthBytes]
               intLength = fromIntegral len
           (textBytes, st'') <- takeWithState BS.empty st' intLength
           return $ CU.Emit st'' [ TE.decodeUtf8 $ textBytes ]

takeWithState :: Monad m
              => ByteString
              -> [ByteString]
              -> Int
              -> Pipe l ByteString o u m (ByteString, [ByteString])
takeWithState acc state 0 = return (acc, state)
takeWithState acc state neededLen =
    let stateLenSum = foldl' (+) 0 $ map BS.length state
     in if stateLenSum >= neededLen
           then do let (firstChunk:state') = state
                       (neededChunk, pushBack) = BS.splitAt neededLen firstChunk
                       acc' = acc `BS.append` neededChunk
                       neededLen' = neededLen - BS.length neededChunk
                       state'' = if BS.null pushBack
                                    then state'
                                    else pushBack:state'
                   takeWithState acc' state'' neededLen'
           else do aM <- await
                   case aM of
                     Just a -> takeWithState acc (state ++ [a]) neededLen
                     Nothing -> error "to be fixed later"
```

Comment: Is it possible that the four bytes used to encode the length are included in the length?  This would lead to you reading four extra bytes with `protobufBytes <- CB.take intLen`.

Comment: @MattS , sorry, I don't get your question correctly? What do you mean by the length being included in the length?

Comment: In the bytestream you specified, every `protobuf` is preceded by 4 bytes that represent the length (in number of bytes) of the `protobuf`.  My initial theory was that these 4 bytes might actually represent the length of the `protobuf` PLUS the 4 byte length header.  This would result in your code reading 4 bytes past the actual end of the `protobuf`, erroneously consuming the 4 bytes that should represent the length of the next `protobuf`.

Comment: Yes, they are the size of the next PB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For protocol buffer parsing and serializing we use `messageWithLengthPutM` and `messageWithLengthGetM` (see below) but I assume it uses a varint encoding for the length, which is not what you need.  I'd probably try to adapt our implementation below by replacing the `messageWithLength` Get/Put with something like

```
myMessageWithLengthGetM = 
   do size <- getWord32be 
      getMessageWithSize size
```

but I have no idea how to implement the `getMessageWithSize` using the available functions from the protocol buffer package. On the other hand you could just `getByteString` and then "reparse" the bytestring.

Regarding conduits: Have you tried implementing the conduit without `Data.Conduit.Util`?  Something like

```
protobufConduit protobufDecode = loop
   where
      loop = 
         do len <- liftM convertLen (CB.take 4)
            bs <- CB.take len
            yield (protobufDecode bs)
            loop
```

Here's the code we use:

```
pbufSerialize :: (ReflectDescriptor w, Wire w) => Conduit w IO ByteString
pbufSerialize = awaitForever f
    where f pb = M.mapM_ yield $ BSL.toChunks $ runPut (messageWithLengthPutM pb)

pbufParse :: (ReflectDescriptor w, Wire w, Show w) => Conduit ByteString IO w
pbufParse = new
    where
      new = read (runGet messageWithLengthGetM . BSL.fromChunks . (:[]))
      read parse =
          do mbs <- await
             case mbs of
               Just bs -> checkResult (parse bs)
               Nothing -> return ()
      checkResult result =
          case result of
            Failed _ errmsg -> fail errmsg
            Partial cont -> read (cont . Just . BSL.fromChunks . (:[]))
            Finished rest _ msg ->
                do yield msg
                   checkResult (runGet messageWithLengthGetM rest)
```

Comment: Thanks @David Leuschner , since I use Haskell on both sides of the channel, I simply changed my protocol and now use the code of your `pbufSerialize` and `pbufParse` functions :-). The idea of not using `CU.sequenceSink` was crucial. Thanks!